# How is the concave closure operation defined?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, convex-analysis

I learned the in a vector space over an ordered field, the convex closure operation of a subset is defined as  the smallest convex set that contains the subset. I was wondering how the concave closure operation is defined?

I also would like to learn about its properties, which in turn might characterize a closure operation to be a concave closure operation. References are also appreciated.

For example, [Concave closure of a submodular function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Submodular_set_function#Concave_closure)

Consider any vector $x=\{x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n\} \in \mathbb{R}^n$ such that each $0\leq x_i\leq 1$. Then the concave closure of a submodular function $f:2^{\Omega}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is defined as
$$f^+(x)=\max(\sum_S \alpha_S f(S):\sum_S \alpha_S 1_S=x,\sum_S \alpha_S=1,\alpha_S\geq 0).$$

What does $1_S$ mean?

What is the range of $S$ in $\sum_S$?

What is the variable $\max$ is taken over?

In fact, I don't understand how [the convex closure of a submodular function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Submodular_set_function#Convex_closure) is related the convex closure of a subset either.

Thanks and regards!

Comment: It might not necessarily be very related. The "$X$ closure" of a thing usually just means "change the thing as little as possible so that it has the property $X$". For example, the convex closure of a set arises in some sense by adding the fewest necessary elements to the set so that it becomes convex. See also [transitive closure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transitive_closure), [algebraic closure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_closure).

Answer (score 2):

This is not a subject about which I really know anything, but I can at least answer the notational questions.

$S$ ranges over subsets of $\Omega=\{1,2,\dots,n\}$. $1_S$ is the [indicator (or characteristic) function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indicator_function) of $S$. Or rather, it’s the vector of values of the indicator function, $\langle 1_S(1),1_S(2),\dots,1_S(n)\rangle$. The maximum is taken over all convex combinations $\alpha_S$ of $S\subseteq\Omega$ such that $\sum_S\alpha_S1_S=x$; in a slightly expanded form it’s

$$f^+(\mathbf{x})=\max\left\{\sum_{S\subseteq\Omega}\alpha_Sf(S):\sum_{S\subseteq\Omega}\alpha_S1_S=\mathbf{x}\text{ and }\sum_{S\subseteq\Omega}\alpha_S=1,\text{ where each }\alpha_S\ge0\right\}\;.$$

Comment: +1.Thank! I think $x$ is a n dimensional vector, but $\alpha_S$ and $1_S$ are both scalar valued, so how does $\sum_S \alpha_S 1_S = x$ make sense?

Comment: @Tim: Yes, $\mathbf{x}$ is a point in the $n$-dimentional unit hypercube. $1_S$ is vector-valued: it’s actually $\langle 1_S(1),\dots,1_S(n)\rangle$. Suppose that $n=5$ and $S=\{1,4\}$; then $\alpha_S1_S=\langle\alpha_S,0,0,\alpha_S,0\rangle$. I’ve now corrected/expanded that bit in the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Convex closure here corresponds to the convex closure of a set of points in $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ (where $n=|\Omega|$) given by $(1_S,f(S))$ for all subsets $S$ of $\Omega$ ($1_S$ is the indicator vector of S in $\mathbb{R}^n$).

A dual representation would be in terms of the submodular polyhedron defined as

$$
P_f = \{x \in \mathbb{R}^n: x^T1_S \leq f(S) \forall S \subseteq \Omega\}
$$

Convex closure of $f$ can now be shown to be same as

$$
f^+(c) = \max_{x \in P_f} c^Tx
$$